# Python how to loop multiple variables and different steps parallel?

Tags: python

How to loop multiple variables and different steps parallel?

Like, in c++, `for(int i=0, j=n-1; i<n && j>=0; i++, j--)`.

Comment: You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through two ranges in parallel.

Comment: @khelwood Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `zip()` to iterate multiple iterables in parallel:

```
for i,j in zip(range(n), range(n-1, -1, -1)):
    print(i, j)
```

Possible output:

```
0 9
1 8
2 7
3 6
4 5
5 4
6 3
7 2
8 1
9 0
```

`zip()` will stop iteration once the first iterator is exhausted. When you want to continue until the last is done, providing fill values for the others, you can use `itertools.zip_longest()`.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `for` loops are usually iterated over a sequence (such as but not limited to: a `list`, `numpy` array, a `range`, `enumerate`d type, `dict` items etc).

The below implementation is a `zip`'d form of two `range` objects:

```
for i, j in zip(range(0, n, 1), range(n-1, -1, -1)):
    print(i, j)
```

The limitation in this approach is that the two sequences (one over `i` and one over `j` must be of the same length.

However, if say `i` iterates over `n` elements and `j` over `m` elements, then the number of times the loop will be executed will be `min(i, j)`, i.e., the execution exits the loop as soon as one of the sequences is completed.

Comment: no they don't have to. try `for i, j in zip([1, 2], 'foobar'): `; it stops on the smallest

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Saw your comment after my edit! I noticed that right after I wrote my answer as well.